# "No testable files found." when trying to run NUnit though final builder

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit, finalbuilder

I'm trying to run Nunit unit tests using finalbuilder/continua and it's simply not working and I don't know why. I just get this error:

[image]

> No testable files found. Check that you have entered valid paths for
>   the Files field. Also ensure that the Workspace and Repository Rules
>   are set up correctly to copy the files to the agent.

I have the following configuration:

[image]

I'm building the dll before hand:

[image]

I can see the dll in (what I think is) the right directory:

[image]

I turned on verbose logging but it's not helpful. I just get the same information again:

```
Medium: 08:52:38.824 {T12} [Debug] Running action 'NUnit MES_Helpers_Test (NUnitAction)'. 
Medium: 08:52:38.840 {T12} [Execute Action] Action 'NUnit MES_Helpers_Test' has failed due to an error: No testable files found. Check that you have entered valid paths for the Files field. Also ensure that the Workspace and Repository Rules are set up correctly to copy the files to the agent. 
Medium: 08:52:38.840 {T12} [Debug] Running action 'Build solution (MSBuildAction)'.
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an 's' missing from your file path.

Change:

> $Workspace$\Output\MES_Helpers_Test\MES_Helpers_Test.dll

to

> $Workspace$\Output\MES_Helpers_Test\MES_Helpers_Test**s**.dll